# qgis2web Attribute Filter not showing in preview or final export

Tags: qgis, leaflet, qgis2web

I'm using the latest version of QGIS and I want to make a web map (through the Leaflet option) for which i'm using the 'qgis2web' plugin. It is able to show the locations on the map (which i imported through a shapefile) BUT when I go to "Appearance", select a "Attribute Filter" like "state_name" in this case. And I click on "Update Preview" then the Attribute Filter does not show up. (Check the image below):

[image]

Ideally, it should appear like this (this is a screenshot from a tutorial):

[image]

Can anyone help me on what is possibly going wrong?

I tried using a different computer to do the same but I'm getting the same result.

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out. I just had to change the "Template" option to "full-screen" instead of "canvas-size".